# For X.509 Certificates where is the actual digital signature?

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, x.509

When you open up the certificate information from your browser and go to the details tab there is a bunch of information for various certificate fields. I am wondering which field contains the actual digital signature value?

Comment: Which one are you using? Also, what is your goal in seeing the signature?

Comment: the one labeled "Certificate Signature Value" ?

Comment: I'm using google chrome and there is no field for "Certificate Signature Value". There is a drop down in the details tab for "Version 1 Fields", "Extensions only", "Critical Extensions Only" and "Properties only". None of the fields for each category seem to indicate the signature value. I wanted to see it out of curiosity after learning how certificates worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
[image]

Comment: for those who are not able to see the image, it's the one labeled "Certificate Signature Value"